# Como mostrar "Janelas" de acordo com dia da Semana

Tags: javascript

Tenho um cardápio de segunda a sábado, e preciso expor isso de acordo com a semana.

Comment: Que quer dizer com "Janelas"?

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    //retorna um numero de 0 (domingo) a 6 (sabado)
    var n = d.getDay() ;
    //mostra a div com id igual ao numero correspondente ao dia da semana dado acima
    $("#"+n).show();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="0" style="display:none;">
     <h3>Cardápio domingo</h3>
     <p>Churrasco regado a cerveja R$2,50</p>

</div>
<div id="1" style="display:none;">
     <h3>Cardápio segunda-feira</h3>
      <p>Sopão R$0,50</p>

</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none">
     <h3>Cardápio terça-feira</h3>
      <p>Feijoada completa R$2,10</p>

</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none">
     <h3>Cardápio quarta-feira</h3>
      <p>Rodizio de massas e pizzas R$2,00</p>
</div>
<div id="4" style="display:none">
     <h3>Cardápio quinta-feira</h3>
      <p>Frutos do mar R$2,05</p>

</div>
<div id="5" style="display:none">
     <h3>Cardápio sexta-feira</h3>
      <p>Bacalhau a sua moda R$3,50</p>

</div>
<div id="6" style="display:none">
     <h3>Cardápio sabado</h3>
      <p>Pão e água R$455,50</p>

</div>
```

> [O método getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) retorna o dia da semana para a data especificada de acordo com a hora local, onde 0 representa o Domingo